# Is it legal to modify MIT licensed code and sell it?

Tags: commercial, mit-license

I have a project and I want to use a ready-made script that is licensed under MIT in it. But using this script separately will be redundant.

So I've decided to merge my code and the MIT licensed script in the same file. (Let's say I'll modify, improve and/or add new features to it.)

I'm planning to sell this work on a market, but is it fair (legally)?

NOTE: Meanwhile, I'll put (refer) the MIT licensed script's copyright already in the final file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes

From the MIT License:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, **modify**, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or **sell copies** of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or **substantial portions** of the Software.

Make sure you include the license in your source code and you should be fine. It would probably be good of you to at some point fully open source your project but I don't believe that's a requirement.

Long Answer: Talk to a Lawyer/Barrister/Legal Professional in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Even shorter answer: "yes".

Comment: @tdammers that'd be below post limit ;)

Comment: +1 but I suggest you do edit the post so that the first line is "short answer: yes"